# "System program problem detected do you want to report problem now ? Cancel | Report problem..."

Tags: system, update-notifier

Update-notifier shows:
"System program problem detected
do you want to report problem now ?
Cancel | Report problem..."

whenever I start ubuntu 18.04. I have reported problem many times and also canceled a lot.

Comment: See http://errors.ubuntu.com for what happens when you click "Report problem"

Answer (score 0):

- Step 1 : go to /var/crash folder.
  -Step 2 : Check if any files are there.
  If yes its because of these files OS is complaining
  -Step 3 : based on the file name we can makeout which process has crashed and complaining.
  -Step4 : In my case virtualbox process has crashed and was ok with deleting those files.
  -Step 5 : When once all files are removed from the folder did not see any reporting by linux.

-Please check if this input works.